# Merge Two JSON array columns in Mysql 8

Tags: mysql, sql, arrays, json, aggregate-functions

I am using Mysql (version > 8).

I have a table where I am storing unique customer ids for the day in an JSON field as an array.

I need to query for all unique customers in last 30 days. I am unable to find an equivalent mysql query for the same.

I am using `JSON_ARRAYAGG` to first merge all the arrays and then I am using ruby to flatten the array and find uniq values.

Example Query:

```
SELECT 
    JSON_ARRAYAGG(customers) as customers, 
    name 
FROM `source_type_daily_metrics` 
WHERE 
    `source_type_daily_metrics`.`merchant_id` = 29 
    AND (date >= curdate() - interval 30 day) 
GROUP BY `source_type_daily_metrics`.`name`
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `json_table()` to unnest the arrays as rows, and then `json_arrayagg()` to aggregate back:

```
select s.name, json_arrayagg(t.cust) customers
from source_type_daily_metrics s
cross join json_table(s.customers, '$[*]' columns (cust int path '$')) t
where s.merchant_id = 29 and date >= current_date - interval 30 day
group by s.name
```

If there are duplicate customer ids across arrays, and you want distinct values in the resultset, then you need an additional level of aggregation (since, unfortunately, `json_arrayagg()` does not support `distinct`):

```
select name, json_arrayagg(cust) customers
from (
    select distinct s.name, t.cust
    from source_type_daily_metrics s
    cross join json_table(s.customers, '$[*]' columns (cust int path '$')) t
    where s.merchant_id = 29 and date >= current_date - interval 30 day
) t
group by s.name
```